# WordPress - How do I stop a Gutenberg Block from firing multiple GET Requests?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

## Fixed it!

### How did I fix it?

Well, after looking for every documentation and question around fetching, I remembered that a button with a `function` with parenthesis always fires. The moment I removed the parenthesis it stopped the infinite loop of `GET` requests.

`<button onclick={fetchingId}>Chercher le produit</button>`

Now, the issue is that it doesn't seem to work and the function doesn't fire.
I am currently trying a few Gutenberg components to help me fire that function and fetch the API on demand.

#### Edit

Someone made me notice that I should pass the function and not its result.

The function inside the `onclick` should be:

`() => fetchingId(attributes.ids)`

I switched the HTML button with a Component names `<Button>`:

```
<Button
    isPrimary
    className='fetch-product'
    onClick={() => fetchingId(attributes.ids)}>
        Chercher un produit
</Button>
```

---

From the WordPress StackExchange somebody told me that we shouldn't use functions inside a React component and use `useEffect` instead.

[The other thread with a solution.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383147/how-to-stop-a-gutenberg-block-from-firing-multiple-get-requests/383150#383150)

### The original post:

I've been building a Gutenberg Block that sends a `GET` request to the Woocommerce REST API.

It is composed of a text `input` that receives an ID of a product and fetches it to the Woocommerce REST API. It also has a `button` that fires a function to fetch the product  with the API.

#### The issue with the GET Requests

The fetching works well, but it keeps sending multiple `GET` requests, even when I do not click the button to fire the function. Simply clicking the input sends multiple requests when i only need one everytime I change the ID.

#### The code

This is the first part of the edit function:

```js
const edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    // Wrapped the WooCommerce.get() function in a function named `fetchingId` to call it with a button
    const fetchingId = async (id) => {
      // The WooCoommerce.get() function
      const response = await WooCommerce.get(`products/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setAttributes({ price: response.data.price });
          setAttributes({ name: response.data.name });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          setAttributes({ price: '' });
          setAttributes({ name: '' });
        });
    }

    ...

  }
```

This is another part of the function: an input that updates the `Product ID` that is used for the `GET` request and a button linked to the `fetchingId()` function.

```
return <div {...blockProps}>
    <div class="wrapper-input" >
        <TextControl
          label={__('ID du Produit', 'ingredient-unique')}
          value={attributes.id}
          onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ id: val })}
          className='control-id'
        />
    </div>
    <button onclick={fetchingId(attributes.id)}>Chercher le produit</button>

    ...
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed it!

### How did I fix it?

Well, after looking for every documentation and question around fetching, I remembered that a button with a function with parenthesis always fires. The moment I removed the parenthesis it stopped the infinite loop of `GET` requests.

`<button onclick={fetchingId}>Chercher le produit</button>`

Now, the issue is that it doesn't seem to work and the function doesn't fire. I am currently trying a few Gutenberg components to help me fire that function and fetch the API on demand.
Edit

Someone made me notice that I should pass the function and not its result.

The function inside the onclick should be:

`() => fetchingId(attributes.ids)`

I switched the HTML button with a Component names :

```
<Button
    isPrimary
    className='fetch-product'
    onClick={() => fetchingId(attributes.ids)}>
        Chercher un produit
</Button>
```

From the WordPress StackExchange somebody told me that we shouldn't use functions inside a React component and use `useEffect` instead.